# How to resolve C# errors in my code?

Tags: c#

I'm a C# beginner (3-day experience). Today I'm practising the inheritance in C#. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Geometry
{
public class Geometry
{
    public double perimeter;
    public double area;
    public bool special;
}

public class Rect : Geometry
{
    public void Rectangle( double length, double width )
    {
        perimeter = (length + width) * 2;
        area = length * width;
        special = (length == width) ? true : false;

        Console.WriteLine("Rectangle information: ");
        Console.WriteLine("Perimeter: " + perimeter);
        Console.WriteLine("Area: " + area);
        if (special) Console.WriteLine("This is a special rectangle. In fact, this is a square!");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

public class Cir : Geometry
{
    public void Circle(double radius)
    {
        perimeter = radius * 2 * Math.PI;
        area = radius * radius * Math.PI;

        Console.WriteLine("Perimeter: " + perimeter);
        Console.WriteLine("Area: " + area);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Rectangle a = new Rectangle(23.00, 21.4);
        Circle b = new Circle(5.8);
    }
}
```

The compiler said that "The type or namespace of 'Rectangle' could not be found", same as Circle. What's wrong? I don't really understand although I tried many ways to fix them. How can I find and understand the errors?

Comment: Your classes are called `Rect` and `Cir`. Those are their names. Use their names, not different names.

Comment: Adding to @EdPlunkett comment, not only that but you also specify `void` in your constructor definitions. This is incorrect, it should be simply `public Rectangle(double length, double width)` (or `Rect` instead since that's the actual class name) and `public Circle(double radius)` (again, or `Circ`).

Comment: @sab669 `Rectangle` is not the name of the class. I think you're right that he intended those to be constructors, but he needs to name them correctly as well.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yea I just editted my comment noting that :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the error.  You never wrote a class named `Rectangle`.  `Rect` is not the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 errors.

Error #1 is that your constructor name and your class name are not the same

Error #2 is that the constructor cannot have a return type (void)

```
public class Rectangle
{
    public Rectangle(double length, double width)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should focus some of your learning on knowing the difference between a `class` and a `method`.

In your code you have created the following two classes:

```
public class Cir : Geometry

public class Rect : Geometry
```

Yet when you instantiate the classes in your `Main()` method you do not call them by their class name, instead by the `void` methods you have defined for each:

```
Rectangle a = new Rectangle(23.00, 21.4);
Circle b = new Circle(5.8);
```

What you likely want to do is rename both classes to Rectangle and Circle add a [Constructor](https://www.dotnetperls.com/constructor) to each class that takes the parameters you want.

```
public class Circle : Geometry
{
    public Circle(double radius)
    {
        perimeter = radius * 2 * Math.PI;
        area = radius * radius * Math.PI;
    }
}
```

Try to keep your methods light, restricting them to a single responsibility or purpose and name the accordingly.  For instance in your `Geometry` class, you could add a `void PrintDetails()` method or even better a `void PrintArea()` **AND** a `void PrintPerimeter()` method:

```
public class Geometry
{
    public double perimeter;
    public double area;
    public bool special;

    public void PrintArea()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Area: " + area);
    }

    public void PrintPerimeter()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Perimeter: " + perimeter);
    }
}
```

Comment: What an explicit answer! Thanks for your help <3

Answer (score 0):

You can only create instances/objects of classes. Your class names are

```
Rect
```

and

```
Cir
```

Your Object names of these classes here are

> a

and

> b

respectively. so Your code should be

```
 Rect  a = new Rect; 
 a.Rectangle(23.00, 21.4); //Calls your method using Rect class object
 Cir  b = new Cir; 
 b.Circle(5.8);//Calls your method using Cir class object
```

Answer (score -1):

The class you define is "Rect" as example. Now while you may think that is  an abbreviation to "Rectangle", the compiler has a more altruistic point of view - it is NOT the same, so error.

Same with "Circ".

Now, both classes have CONSTRUCTORS with the proper name (which thus are not constructors) but the class names themselves - are wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You did not closed the namespace geometry.
You can create an instance of Rect(class) or Cir, not Rectangle(method) or Circle.